# git clone using ssh connection fails "Connection reset by <server_IP> port 7999"

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket

I want to clone bitbucket repository using ssh authentication as cloning through https method gives connection timed out error for one of my repository which is 1Gb+ in storage.

I generated ssh keys using "ssh-keygen" on windows client, public key (id_rsa) is added to my bitbucket account. Settings -->Manage Account ---> SSH keys

Bitbucket DataCenter is hosted on Azure linux(Ubuntu) vm, default ssh port 7999 is whitelisted on azure firewall for my machine ip and there is no internal firewall activated on linux server.

My account is having system admin rights.

**git clone ssh://git@serverURL:7999/dem/projectname.git**

**Error Message:**

```
Cloning into 'projectname'...
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by Server_ip port 7999
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Also I tried adding "sshd: mySystem_IP" in /etc/hosts.allow on bitbucket server still getting the same error.

Has anyone faced similar kind of issue? Not sure what am I missing in the configuration here. Thank you for your time!

**Debug using ssh -vT:**

```
ssh -vT ssh://git@bitbucket_url.com:7999
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l 24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to Server_IP port 7999.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by Server_IP port 7999
```

Comment: Use several more `v`s in your debug. Probably what's happening is that your ssh and their sshd can't agree on a key exchange algorithm. (Note that old ssh programs try to use insecurely-small RSA keys, and newer sshd's say no. This can also go the other way, with newer clients refusing to talk to old servers.)

Comment: @phd output after using traceroute command: "Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `bitbucket_url [http://localhost:7990]' on position 1 (argc 5)"

Comment: @torek Tried with multiple V's still getting the same debug output. How can I determine if any one , windows client or linux server are using old sshd due to which one is refusing to connect?

Comment: Normally you'd get some `debug2` and `debug3` messages, e.g., `debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c` shows which key exchange algorithms I had as options for my `ssh -Tvvv git@github.com`.

Comment: You have OpenSSH 8.8p1 on your system (see first line of output) and it's pretty modern. so I'd suspect the bitbucket server system has an out of date sshd on it.

Comment: right catch @torek, ssh -V on server gave `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.0.2n ` will try to update the ssh version to 8.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your inputs for the question, really appreciated. It helped me gain new information.
However even after updating OpenSSH to latest version as suggested by @torek I was facing the same issue.
Finally I tried using a different encryption algorithm than default RSA.

```
ssh-keygen uses RSA by default for generation of access keys.
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "Comment"  uses elliptic curve cryptography
```

**ssh-keygen -t ed25519 worked for me**

SSH Key location: C:\Users\UserName.ssh
Copy the key contents from file *id_ed25519.pub* and add this public key into your Bitbucket account.
Settings -->Manage Account ---> SSH keys

This will establish the connection with Bitbucket server and your repository will be cloned without any issue using ssh url.

`git clone <ssh_repository_url>`